# How to switch user roles with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I would like to create users with different roles in my specs, but I am failing to do it properly.

User

```
belongs_to :role
```

Role

```
has_many :users
```

Roles factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :role do
    name "teacher"
  end

  factory :student, parent: :role do
    name "student"
  end

end
```

User factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'test@gmail.com'
    password '12345678'
    password_confirmation '12345678'

    role
  end
end
```

Spec

```
let(:app_user)  { FactoryGirl.create(:app_user) }
let!(:app_user2)  { FactoryGirl.create(:app_user, role: "student") }
```

I know there's a mistake, but can't figure it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `association:`, that way:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    association: :role
    email 'test@gmail.com'
    password '12345678'
    password_confirmation '12345678'
  end
end
```

or define aliases - you can read about them [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#aliases).